# Remove markers from map (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing an app with Google maps that should display several categories on a map. Now I would like to have the possibility to add markers from several categories and delete them as well if necessary.

I've managed to figure out the whole thing. At least, almost... I'm having troubles with the removal of the markers of a category. I've created a live demo on jsfiddle to make this clear.
So here's how I attempt to do this:

### CODE

First I initialize the map, etc. (but that is not relevant here). Then I add the markers on the map:

```
for(i in markers){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].latitude, markers[i].longitude),
        visible: true,
        data: category
    });
    newMarkers.push(marker);
}
```

As you can see I have 'data: category' in the object. This is something that's not google maps api, but it gives me no errors and gives me the possibility to search the array when I want to remove the markers. Here the removeMarker function:

```
function removeMarkers(category)
{
    for(i in newMarkers) {
        if(newMarkers[i]['data'] == category){
            count ++;
            newMarkers[i].setMap(null); 
            newMarkers.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

It does remove markers, but not all of them...
Does anyone have solution to my problem?

### [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/helenastandaert/GJUcy/)

Thanks in advance,

Helena S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that you are iterating the newMarkers array and at the same time removing elements from it.
Try this instead. It only sets the removed marker values in the array to null then, after the loop, filters those null values:

```
    for(i in newMarkers) {
        if(newMarkers[i]['data'] == category){
            count ++ 
            newMarkers[i].setMap(null); 
            newMarkers[i] = null;
        }
    }
    newMarkers = newMarkers.filter(function(val){ return !!val; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GJUcy/